# How does s.compare member function behave in the C++ code below?

Tags: c++, string

I have this C++ code below to solve for a homework and after I ran it with Code::Blocks, it tells me that i=0, which means the expression `s.compare(t)<0` is false. But, the way I see it, it's the other way around: (`s<t`, because `AbcA < AAbcA`). Can someone please explain it to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
        string s = "Abc", t = "A";
        s=s+t;
        t=t+s;
        int i = s.compare(t)<0;
        int j = s.length()<t.length();
        cout<<i+j<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is AbcA < AAbcA? That could only be true if the comparison is case sensitive and 'b' < 'A', but it's the other way around: A = 65 and b = 98 in ASCII and Unicode.

Comment: `<` does not result in an `int`, so why are you storing it that way?

Comment: @Rup he does `s=s+t;
            t=t+s;` which is very confusing. After it `s=AbcA; t=AAbcA`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I now see those strings are in the question. They were originally hidden behind an unescaped <

Comment: so letters from both strings, starting with the 0th position have their ASCII value compared, and when one is being bigger/smaller than each other, it stops comparing the remaining characters ? and says that s1<s2/s1>s2 ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: `starting with the 0th position have their ASCII value compared, and when one is being bigger/smaller than each other, it stops comparing the remaining characters ? and says that s1<s2/s1>s2 ?` - generally yes

Comment: ok, I understand now. I believed the sum of the ASCII values of characters from each strings are compared with each other, and if the total value of s1 is hypothetically 700, and s2 has 701, then s1<s2. But now I see this is not the case, and the proper operation of the compare member.

Comment: @painkiller cppreference.com is usually a good place to look for the behavior of standard library functions

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for your clear and concise answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reference [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)  returns:

> negative value if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
>
> zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
>
> positive value if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

[Lexicographical comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) being defined as:

> Lexicographical comparison is a operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
>     The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.

`"AbcA"` comes lexicographically **after** `"AAbc"`, because the first nonequal character `'b'` (ASCII 0x62) comes **after** `'A'` (ASCII 0x41)